# Eliminar atributo Unique en columna

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada usuarios, la cual tiene un campo email con atributo UNIQUE(), pero quiero que ya no sea unique, quiero que sea un campo normal, pero hasta hora lo he intentado y tengo errores.

```
 email          | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |
```

de esta forma

```
DROP INDEX email ON usuarios;
```

Regresa este error:

> No puedo ELIMINAR 'email'. compuebe que el campo/clave existe

o de esta forma

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios DROP INDEX email
```

Regresa este error

> ## 1091 - No puedo ELIMINAR 'email'. compuebe que el campo/clave existe

no se de que otra manera quitar este atributo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Unique` es un tipo de `INDEX` entonces si lo que deseas es eliminarlo como atributo de tu columna, prueba con el siguiente comando:

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios DROP INDEX email;
```

- El comando anterior debería quitar el atributo en cuestión.
- Los datos de tu columna `email` no deberían verse afectados, es decir no deben borrarse
- Comprueba si dicho atributo fue eliminado haciendo un `DESCRIBE tablaNomnre` a tu tabla.

**Referencias**

- [Index Unique en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-unique)
- [Drop Index en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-index.html)

Comment: Gracias Aprendiz... habia un comando para consultar los index, y ahi me di cuenta que el nombre de index era otro, no mail, muy amable por dedicar tiempo en responder.

Comment: SHOW INDEX FROM